# MVC3 _Layout.cshtml...disableing/enabling menu items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, menu

I have an MVC3 C#.Net project.  When I initially load my Web site, I want to route to an Index page and have the navigation tabs at the top of the screen be disabled until a selection is made.  Once a selection is made, the site routes to a details page.  I would then like to enable the navigation menu itmes.  How can I do this?  Pass a ViewBag around?  Not sure

Comment: Are the navigation items only valid on the Details page?  What if I go back to the Index page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.  @CodeRush's answer is cool, which I will use in another scenario.  But I like the implementation, below, for my prticular situation.  In the Object1Controller Index get Action, I added the below code:

```
ViewBag.Hidden = "hidden";
```

Then in the Details get Action, which is the Action called when a link is clicked on the Index view, I added this code:

```
ViewBag.Hidden = "visible";
```

Then in the _Layout.cshtml I added this code:

```
 <li style="visibility: @ViewBag.Hidden">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
```

Which renders as:

```
<li style="visibility: hidden"><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
```

or

```
<li style="visibility: visible"><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
```

In the other Controllers, I don't need to set the ViewBag.Hidden property since the default for the visibility attribute is "visible".  For the other Controllers, the ViewSource shows:

```
<li style="visibility: "><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
```

Which renders as visible

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that Index page doesn't follow a layout of the rest of the website, therefore index page shouldn't use a master layout.

On your index page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index page";
    // Null or a custom layout
    Layout = null;
}

<p>Your content below</p>
```

If you want to render a menu on some condition, then store menu in a partial view model, e.g. SiteNavigation.cshtml

You can then render this view based on some condition. E.g.

```
@if(true){
   @{ Html.RenderPartial("SiteNavigation"); }
}
```

Comment: @CodeRush....cool idea.  I like the partial render.  I didn't know that was available.  I also came up with a soluition.  See below.  Thanks

Comment: I think that's the problem for quite a few people (including myself i guess). They jump in without knowing how many tools are at their disposal.